# How do I align these elements to be the way I want?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am working on an online composition notebook. Students would be able to use this without "losing" their notebook before a check... I need various elements aligned, but can't figure out how...

Link to project: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15YrZ5XkcyoyuAsVE29BSA-UEa67GmyBf?usp=sharing

What I wanted to happen is roughly created in Microsoft paint, but it is the basic gist of what the final UI, (Excluding the Title bar, and other stuff), should look like.

I tried using `style="float:left"` for the textbox inputs, and `style="float:right"` for the image, but it didn't work.

Thinking about it though, I still have a lot to learn, an example being of how I would be able to overlay the text over the image... I just thought it would be good enough of basic code to get some sort of help...

---

EDIT: Now that I have researched what this program does, the more I realize that so many more programs do it so efficiently... I have, in the end, decided to abandon the project.

Answer (score 0):

It was the `display: inline-block;` that wouldn't let you align it. Simply align it like below.

```html
<div style="text-align: left;">Left</div>
<div style="text-align: center; display: inline-block;">Center</div>
<div style="text-align: center;">Center</div>
<div style="text-align: right;">Right</div>
```